# how to convert below sql query to ElasticSearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to get data from column1 and column2, both of these columns can have the asked data. I want the result to be ordered with data from column1 and then followed by data from column2

SQL Query :

> select  * from table_name where column1='first1' or column2='first1'
>   order by column1, column2

## Please Consider below data

column1     column2

---

first2      first1

first1      last1

first3      last3

last3       last4

first1      last4

## Result should be

column1     column2

---

first1      last1

first1      last4

first2      first1

I want to get an elastic query for similar results. Thanks in advance.

Comment: HI,

I tried using sorting concept but it happen after fetching the data. but i need at time of querying.

i have used below query, in that where i need to add order by clause

Comment: {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "what": {
              "query": "ABC",
              "operator": "and"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Comment: here  the "what" field is combination of column_name,column_last_name,used copy_to  concept for what field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use custom scoring for data. I think this is what you want. by using this scoring, data that has the `ABC` in first field will have more score than data that has it in second column.

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "match": {
                "column_name": "ABC"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "column_last_name": "ABC"
              }
            }
          ],
          "minimum_should_match": 1
        }
      },
      "script_score": {

        "script": {
          "params":{
            "word" : "ABC"
          },
          "inline" : "if(_source.column_name.equals(word)){return 2;} else if(_source.column_last_name.equals(word)){return 1;}"
        }
      },
      "boost_mode": "replace"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay,Do't consider about the data. please consider how to convert a bove mentioned  sql to ElasticSearch Json query.

there is two scenarios one is column_name will match OR column_last_name will match but i want to display only  column_last_name matched data,after column_name

Comment: I don't understand your mean. this is the exactly conversion of your sql query. are you want to match data on two columns in same time or separately?

Comment: same time, i have updated my question please find

Comment: according to your edit, my answer sort the data as you expected

Comment: Thanks for your answer. it is ordering the data According to Alphabetical, i need the order is matched condition, means if column_name data matched then display the that row,after  column_last_name matched data row

Comment: I want to sort the data at the time of querying, i think sort is working like after getting the data it sorting according Desc

Comment: I really don't understand. please provide another sample data and the result output ( give data that do not ordered by Alphabet)

Comment: I edited my answer, hope it useful

Comment: please try it and give me feed back